# How do I get an image from an UIButton?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

I have Custom Buttons in my application in which I have set images. I want to get image from button and stored in UIImage variable. Kindly Guide me.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

How about this?

```
UIImage *img = [button imageForState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Please how can I get the image name?

Comment: I don’t think that’s possible.

Comment: for background image of UIButton
UIImage *img =  [button backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal];

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3.0** syntax

```
let image: UIImage = yourButton.image(for: .normal)!
```

Answer (score 0):

`UIImage *myNewImage = [UIButton imageForState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Though this isn't very good design practice. I would do  this:

`UIImage *myNewImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"name of image that is in your bundle"];`

Comment: Sometimes the image isn't in your bundle. Maybe it has been set dynamically from a server or user's photo library.